# spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 does not support message handler

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming-kafka

My use case is to print offset number , partition , topic for each record that has been read from kafka from a spark streaming application.

currently my code to create discrete stream looks like this.

```
val stream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, params, topicPartition_map)
)
```

but to get metadata about each record i need to pass in message handler..
so i am expecting to use something like this..

```
val messageHandler = { mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (mmd.topic, mmd.key, mmd.message)

val stream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, params, topicPartition_map),
  messageHandler
)
```

or

```
val messageHandler = { mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (mmd.topic, mmd.key, mmd.message)
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, String, String)](
      ssc, params, topicPartition_map,messageHandler)
```

but the createDirectStream is not available with method argument that accepts message handler..

my sbt dependency is.

> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %%
> "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
> exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")
> exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.module","*") scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
> val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"

Comment: Have you try spark structured streaming for kafka?.

Comment: whats the difference ?

Comment: For kafka version 0.10 you must use structured streaming. More in official docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: i am not sure ,what you mean by that. do you mean i should use spark
  .readStream instead of KafkaUtils.createDirectStream ?

Comment: yep, that'll do. Just make sure that you follow the deploying section carefully.

Comment: can you point out specific document why i should use readStream instead of createDirectStream , as i dont really understand how one is defined as structured streaming and other is not .. i also dont get it why 0.8 version had message handler in createDirectStream method but not in 0.10..

Comment: what does `val messageHandler = { mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (mmd.topic, mmd.key, mmd.message)
` do?